# Joints velocity units

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi!

This is quite a simple question. What are the units that Gazebo uses for joints velocity? what do we get with GetVelocity? or what do we set with SetVelocity?
I checked the Joints class reference, but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3955/joints-velocity-units/) by [atenea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/403/atenea/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

All units in Gazebo standard SI (meters, seconds, radians, etc).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atenea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/403/atenea/) on 2013-07-31**:
thanks!